# Ionic Facebook plugin work only on one phone

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, facebook-login

I'm building an Ionic app with Facebook Login support.
I'm setting all as required in the developer.facebook.com settings and on config.xml on ionic config.
The login works fine for only my phone.

On every other phone the method `facebook.login(['email'])` reject Promise and pass an empty error.

How is it possible, counting that every configuration is compiler-related and not phone-related? There isn't config that uses device information.

Is really strange because I'm expecting does or doesn't work everywhere.

On every phone I've tried, Facebook app is installed and logged. No Facebook Lite installed.

Answer (score 0):

Find the problem.
Facebook dev app was is develop mode so only me can access.
Possible solutions are:

1. Make in prod mode the app
2. Add other users facebook account to tester list